# Display TOC title as a heading (or hide it altogether) in reStructuredText

Tags: github, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, tableofcontents

I needed a table of contents for a reStructuredText (.rst) document I was editing, so I added

```
.. contents:: Table of Contents
```

in the appropriate place and it works fine.

Problem is, at least in GitHub's RST parser/renderer/whatever, the "Table of Contents" title displays just like normal, non-header text would, when I want a level 2-heading instead.

[Here's the README.rst file](https://github.com/duffn/dumb-password-rules/blob/1c8060581736d8a289413359f81bc97bde05b72e/README.rst#contributing) I'm trying to change. Notice how "Table of Contents" looks not so much like a section header or title.

Is there a way to either

1. style the TOC title like a level 2-heading, or
2. disable the TOC title altogether, so I could just add my own? (something like the following)

   ```
   Table of Contents
   -----------------
   .. contents:: :disable_title: true
   ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable the TOC title by combining the [`:local:` option](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#table-of-contents) with omission of the TOC title:

```
Your h2 level title here
------------------------
.. contents::
   :local:
```

But note that the local option **localizes the TOC to only list subsections of the section in which it is placed** rather than listing every section in the document. If you still want to include everything, make a top-level header and place the TOC directly beneath it. This will still exclude the top-level header itself, however.